# Роутинг и навигация в Angular2

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

Есть менюшка menu1 которая меняет содержание блока block1. При этом меняется и url ("/", "/photo", "/video", "/about" и т.д.)
Это легко можно осуществить при помощи router-outlet.

Но что если внутри блока block1, на одной из страниц, будет еще одна менюшка menu2, которая будет точно так же менять содержание уже блока block2? При этом она должна менять url соответствующим образом ("/photo/album1", "/photo/album2", и т.д.). Т.е. приплюсовывать подгруппу.

Перезагрузка страницы недопустима. Обноваляться/меняться должен только блок, над которым происходит манипуляция. Т.е. меню menu2 не должна менять весь блок block1, а только block2. Ума не приложу, как это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

router-outlet внутри router-outlet!

Роутинг подстраниц будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
{ path: 'photo', component: SubComponent, children: [
  {path: '', component: SubPage0Component},
  {path: 'album1', component: SubPage1Component},
  {path: 'album2', component: SubPage2Component}
]}
```